# Ansible: return value from playbook

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to return a value from one included playbook to use in another? Consider the following playbook:

```
 ---
 - include: provisionPostgres.yml store=09123
 - include: provisionWebserver.yml store=09123
```

Each of these included playbooks provisions an AWS instance, and then installs software on that instance. Postgres and my web app respectively.

The use case I'm trying to handle is to have the first included playbook return the IP address of my database server so that I can use it to point my web server to in the 2nd included playbook.

I know that I can register values from tasks to use in other tasks, but I can't find out how to return a value from a playbook.

How can I accomplish this in ansible?

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not sure how variables behave between playbooks, but if all else fails you could have a local_action: copy content={{ some_variable }} to save it to a file. Just so you know you have an option :-)

Comment: Thanks, Ramon.  I have given thought to grabbing the IP and saving it to a vars file that the next VM in the flow would need.  Just doesn't seem like an elegant solution.  I appreciate your note, though.

Comment: yeah, I agree it's not pretty - that's why I didn't post it as an answer :-). If I have a little time I'll look into the behaviour of vars/facts between playbooks.

Comment: Including a playbook also appears to include the variables set in that playbook.

I am doing the same thing you are with a playbook that gets the IP of an interface, and sets that IP to a variable in that playbook. When I include that playbook in another playbook, the included playbook variable (the IP) is available in the parent playbook.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any such concept as "the output of a playbook". There can be the results of tasks which you can register. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#common

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple circumstances to think about, the methods vary:

1. is the target host the same OR different?
2. are the plays being run sequentially, as individual plays VERSUS importing plays within a single playbook?

**Note:** *the ansible docs on variable scope indicate that variables defined in a play are not available outside that play unless it's being applied to the same set of hosts. Otherwise, you will need to use a var with global scope.*

Target host is the same and playbooks are run consecutively from single run:

```
[root@ansible-server ~]# cat global.yml
---
# Combine multiple playbooks
  - import_playbook: play1.yml
  - import_playbook: play2.yml
[root@ansible-server ~]#

#play1.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
   - name: Register a new value
     shell: echo "/etc/resolv.conf"
     register: PLAY1VAR

   - debug: msg="{{PLAY1VAR.stdout}}"

#play2.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
   - name: Echo PLAY1 variable value
     shell: cat "{{PLAY1VAR.stdout}}" |tail -1
     register: PLAY2_RESULTS

   - debug: msg="{{PLAY2_RESULTS.stdout}}"
```

Target hosts are different, but playbooks are run consecutively from a single run (use a dummy host):

```
#play1.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
   - name: Register a new value
     shell: echo "/etc/resolv.conf"
     register: PLAY1VAR

   - debug: msg="{{PLAY1VAR.stdout}}"

   - name: Register dummy host with variable
     add_host:
       name: "DUMMY_HOST"
       PLAY1VAR_NEW: " {{ PLAY1VAR.stdout }}"

#play2.yml
---
- hosts: 192.168.3.151
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
   - name: Echo PLAY1 variable vaule
     shell: cat {{ hostvars['DUMMY_HOST']['PLAY1VAR_NEW'] }} |tail -1
     register: PLAY2_RESULTS

   - debug: msg="{{PLAY2_RESULTS.stdout}}"
```